# File and Folder Encryption in Powershell

Tags: powershell

[image]I have folder in my D drive containing a notepad file, I want to checked the (Encrypt Contents to Secure data) which is in properties->Advance option using Powershell code.
I tried a lot but didn't find any solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi, SO is not a scriptwriting service. Please provide at least an example of your work (btw, what you want to achieve is possible and actually very easy using Powershell)

Comment: I upload the image,
what I want is that only get checked the "Encrypt Content to Secure Data" option of file using powershell

Comment: Please provide a code sample of your own work so far. Using the default Windows encryption is very easy using Powershell, but before I will post an answer I need to see what you have written so far (SO is not a script writing function). As a hint : try doing Get-Item on a file (stick it in a variable) and then call the Encrypt() function...

Comment: I even don't know what command is used for encryption in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Encryption and Decryption the Encrypt() and Decrypt() functions use as the Following line

```
(get-Item -path "c:\Users\UserName\Desktop\file.txt").Encrypt()
(get-Item -path "c:\Users\UserName\Desktop\file.txt").Decrypt()
```

Comment: How do you do this for directories?